# Angular Reusing Directives and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, controller, singleton

I have written a custom drop down option selector, all well and good, it has functions to go and get data (from a passed in url) to populate a list.

Now what I want to do is reuse this component but...
When I add it into another part of my application, but use a different data set,  it duplicates the data and runs the controllers functions multiple times.

As far as I can understand 1 have two problems, services are singletons so when I run the function to populate some data, because there is only one instance of the service  it just adds it to the current data set.

then the other problem is that controllers do have instances, so now there are two of them, its running the functions in each one.

So the easy solution would be to copy the component and call it a different name, while this might fix the problem, if I wanted to reuse it 10 times, that's 10 copies of the same component, not good.

I come from a OOP Java background, so I'm probably trying to use those techniques in a language that doesn't support it ;)

So I know I have to rethink how to do this, but I've hit a bit of a wall, how is it best to approach this?

Here is (hopefully) a JSFiddle that illustrates what I'm running itno

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('mySelector', function () {
return {
 scope: {
      mydata: '='
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template:'<select ng-model="timePeriodSelection" ng-options="timePeriodOption.name for timePeriodOption in timePeriodOptions"><option value="">Choose time period</option></select>',
controller: function($scope, myService) {
    //$scope.name = 'Superhero';
    console.log('test',$scope.mydata);
    myService.setData($scope.mydata);
    $scope.timePeriodOptions = myService.getData();
  console.log('test2',myService.getData());
    }
 };
});

app.factory('myService', function() {
var _data=[];    
return {
    setData: function(value){
        for (var a=0;a<value.length;a++){
            _data.push(value[a]);
        }
    },
    getData: function(){
        return _data
    }            
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/devonCream/ess9d6q6/

I can't show you the code I have for commercial reasons, but imagine what I'm passing in is actually a url and I have a service that gets the data then stores it in the array in the service/factory, each time it runs it just keeps adding them up!  The code is a mock up demo.

Comment: Could you provide all your code and highlight the issue in a plunker ? (you can fork and edit this one http://plnkr.co/edit/b8sxOLNgGKZ36oQDGJLM?p=preview)

Comment: Sadly not since its closed source, I have however set up a jsfiddle with something that demonstrates my issue,

Answer (score 0):

Something like a custom drop down should be a directive and nothing else.  That said, there are a ton of ways you could achieve what you're trying to do with a directive.  Checkout the [directive walkthroughs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), they're really helpful.

In some way or another you'll probably want to have an isolate scope, use a template, and add a link function.

Example where the items are always the same:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDropdown', function () {
        return {

            scope: {},

            template: '' +
                '<div class="my-dropdown">' +
                    '<div class="my-dropdown-item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.text}}</div>' +
                '</div>',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
            }

        };
    });
```

Example where you pass the items to each instance:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDropdown', function () {
        return {

            scope: {
                items: '='
            },

            template: '' +
                '<div class="my-dropdown">' +
                    '<div class="my-dropdown-item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.text}}</div>' +
                '</div>'

        };
    });
```

**--UPDATE--**

Example where you get the data once in a service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('dataService', function ($http) {
        var items;

        $http.get('http://ab.com/dropdown-items')
        .then(function (res) {
            items = res.data;
        });

        return {
            items: items
        };
    })
    .directive('myDropdown', function (dataService) {
        return {

            scope: {},

            template: '' +
                '<div class="my-dropdown">' +
                    '<div class="my-dropdown-item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.text}}</div>' +
                '</div>',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.items = dataService.items;
            }

        };
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I have something close to this but where do I hold the data?  We are told to hold the data in the factory/service but doing so gives me the duplication issue, I need to access this data in other services to access other services.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what type of data you're talking about?  Data a user enters, data that makes up the drop down choices, something else?

Comment: There data comes from a service that returns XML, I transform this to json, then store the array (in the factory), the problem arrises because the call to get data exists in the controller which, because there are multiple instances of the controller, gets called multiple times and added to the array.  cont.

Comment: My current workaround is to use a variable, passed into the controller, to identify which instance is being used, then just fire the data request on that one instance, feels a bit 'clunky' to me, but the only way I could see to fix the issue, other that storing the data in the controller, which again, I'm told is bad practice.

Comment: Maybe place the call to get the data in a service and have your directive use that service.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

So unless someone can tell me differently, the only way I can see to solve problem this to hold the data in the controller, therefore isolating the data to its own controller instance., holding the data anywhere else just causes instance issues.

I've refactored my 'fiddle' to show 2 different data sources (in this example I've used 2 factories as models), that bring the data back into the controller to be processed and then stored.

Normally if I wasn't reusing the component I would put this logic into the factory, but doing so gives me the problem I had to start with.

Also in my 'real' project I check the variable to 'see' what 'instance' have been triggered and call methods from that, all seems a bit clunky but it seems the only reliable way I can get it to work maybe Angular 2 will resolve these issues.

[Anyway my link to my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devonCream/ess9d6q6/3/)

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('mySelector', function () {
return { 
    scope: true,
    bindToController:  {
        mydata: '@mydata',     
        timePeriodOptions: '='
    },
    controllerAs: 'selCtrl',
    restrict: 'EA',
    template:'<select ng-model="timePeriodSelection" ng-options="timePeriodOption.name for timePeriodOption in selCtrl.timePeriodOptions"><option value="">Choose time period</option></select>',
    controller: 'selCtrl'
 };
});    
app.controller('selCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    var selCtrl = this;    
    selCtrl.timePeriodOptions = [];
    if (angular.isString(selCtrl.mydata)){
        processData();
    }
    function processData(){
        var value = myService.getData(selCtrl.mydata);
        for (var a=0;a<value.length;a++){
            selCtrl.timePeriodOptions.push(value[a]);
        }
    };
});

app.factory('myService', function(dataModel1,dataModel2) {
return {
    getData: function(model){
        var _data = []        
        if (model === "1"){
            _data = dataModel1.getData();
        }else{
            _data = dataModel2.getData();
        }
        console.log('data ',_data);
        return _data
    }            
    }
});
app.factory('dataModel1', function() {
    var _data=[{"name":1,"value":1},{"name":2,"value":2},{"name":3,"value":3}];    
    return {
        getData: function(){
            return _data
        }            
    }
});
app.factory('dataModel2', function() {
    var _data=[{"name":4,"value":4},{"name":5,"value":5},{"name":6,"value":6}];    
    return {
        getData: function(){
            return _data
        }            
    }
});
```